# Are Images assigned in a xib cached?

Tags: ios, ios5, interface-builder, uiimage, xib

If I assign an image to a *UIImage* view in a xib, is that image cached so that if I access the image using *UIImage imageNamed:* I am getting cached Image data?

I'm using iOS 5.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UIImage imageNamed:` does its own cacheing of any images you use. The first time you use it for a given image, it'll populate the cache, and subsequently it'll use the cached version.

`UIImageView` in Interface Builder takes a string to tell it what image to use. It appears that the object that is actually encoded in the Xib to represent the image is a private class called `UIImageNibPlaceholder`, which contains a private NSString variable called `runtimeResourceName`. It's this class that implements the `initWithCoder:` method which is used when the system is loading objects from a xib.

So, the question is, inside `UIImageNibPlaceholder`'s `initWithCoder:`, does it use the `imageNamed:` function of `UIImage`? I think it's reasonable to assume that it does, since the thing stored in the xib is the string `runtimeResourceName`, and the system is turning that string into an actual image when loading the xib.

[This post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/634219#634219) on the Apple developer forums seems to clarify the point (under NDA so I can't copy it here). I couldn't find any publicly accessible information on the subject.

Comment: Hehe. I was all set to just post "Yes", but then I couldn't find much evidence :)

Comment: Very interesting answer! However, I think that it does not use `imageNamed:` because I have a utility for loading h568 images that swizzles the original method and that is not called when the image is set in IB.