# ImageView for all iPhones in Common Sizes

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

So typically on storyboard, you assign an imageview with the image you want (foo.png) and then  the phones automatically upsize to the retina version if one is on the iPhone 4 or 4s (foo@2x.png).

The question is, how do you get an image to display properly on a 4'' iPhone 5? It is all out of whack when I try it in the simulator and Apple has yet to address this situation with a simple solution as they did with the Retina display of the iPhone 4's. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

iPhone 5 support can be added very simply by adding a default@2x-568.png file to your project. Beyond that, it is only a case of making certain the app scales to a new size correctly. Make sure your views accomodate to the new size either programatically, or by setting springs and struts correctly in your UI archives (XIBs or Storyboards as appropriate). You shouldn't need any new images (*). If you already
support retina devices, then you only need to add the new splash screen as above.

(*) If you do for whatever reason, I'd recommend reading this answer:
[ios6 UIImageView - Loading -568h image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567456/ios6-uiimageview-loading-568h-image)

Apple doesn't provide a good way of using different images on the iPhone 5, because you aren't supposed to use any!